# Why is the Raman spectrum continuous?

Tags: raman-spectroscopy

A typical Raman spectrum looks something like this with peaks and a background.[image]
I would like to know
(1) What is the reason for that background?
(2) When I took spectra with quartz the background was very noisy, but with cortisol, the background also becomes very smooth. Does the background also depends upon the materials and if yes why?

Thanking in advance

Comment: It’s not like it’s easy to choose to only measure the photons that come from Raman scattering vs all the other possible processes (yes, there are tricks but they aren’t perfect).